# SQL: Subtract two columns

Tags: sql

```
select content_type_code_id 
    , ABS(price) AS price
    , SUM(case when price >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS debits
    , SUM(case when price < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS credits
from dbo.transaction_unrated  
where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01'
      and transaction_date < '2012/06/01'
      and content_provider_code_id in (1)
group by content_type_code_id, ABS(price) 
ORDER BY ABS(price) ASC
```

The above query produces the following output:

```
content_type_code_id    price   debits  credits
1                      0.00      317    0
1                      0.99      178    1
1                      1.99      786    1
```

But I want something like this:

```
content_type_code_id    price   debits  credits NetCount
    1                      0.00      317    0       317 
    1                      0.99      178    1       177 
    1                      1.99      786    1       785
```

Where NetCount = (debits - credits)

When I try to create another column for that I get an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add:

```
SUM(case when price >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
    SUM(case when price < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NetCount
```

as your last statement, so you'd end up with this:

```
select content_type_code_id 
    , ABS(price) AS price
    , SUM(case when price >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS debits
    , SUM(case when price < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS credits
    , SUM(case when price >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
        SUM(case when price < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NetCount
from dbo.transaction_unrated  
where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01'
      and transaction_date < '2012/06/01'
      and content_provider_code_id in (1)
group by content_type_code_id, ABS(price) 
ORDER BY ABS(price) ASC
```

**Derived table version for Lamak:**

You can also use a derived table to make the code a little cleaner:

```
select content_type_code_id,
    price, debits, credits, (debits - credits) as NetCount
from (
    select content_type_code_id 
        , ABS(price) AS price
        , SUM(case when price >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS debits
        , SUM(case when price < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS credits
    from dbo.transaction_unrated  
    where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01'
          and transaction_date < '2012/06/01'
          and content_provider_code_id in (1)
    group by content_type_code_id, ABS(price) 
) YourDerivedTable
ORDER BY price ASC
```

Comment: +1 - Though I would add to your answer how to do it on a derived table (`SELECT ... debits-credits FROM CuerrentQuery`). I could edit your answer to do it, but I'd rather not mess with your answer ;-)

Comment: @Lamak - ask and ye shall receive

Comment: Thanks for your diligence, It's a more complete answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH tbl AS 
(
select content_type_code_id 
    , ABS(price) AS price
    , SUM(case when price >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS debits
    , SUM(case when price < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS credits
from dbo.transaction_unrated  
where transaction_date >= '2012/05/01'
      and transaction_date < '2012/06/01'
      and content_provider_code_id in (1)
group by content_type_code_id, ABS(price) 
ORDER BY ABS(price) ASC  
)

SELECT content_type_code_id, proce, debits, credits, (debits - credits) netcount from tbl
```

Comment: This won't work on all RDBMS, and currently the question isn't tagged on one, so it may or may not work for the op. (Your syntax will work for SQL Server and probably Oracle, but I'm not sure if it works on other RDBMS)

Comment: @Lamak: the answer is ANSI SQL and thus a perfectly valid answer for a question only tagged with `sql`. CTEs can be seen as a mainstream feature nowadays, just like foreign keys or outer joins. Btw: it would work (at least) in Postgres, DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, Firebird, H2, HSQLDB, Ingres, Vertica, and MonetDB (apart from a slight difference in how date literals are treated though).

Answer (score 1):

Good evening.  I had a similar task and found it to be very short just to add a column and update that.

I think this can be done after your code generates the database.  If it doesn't work for your situation, I would appreciate feedback on that.

ALTER TABLE *name of table here* ADD *NetCount* *integer*;

UPDATE *name of table here* SET *NetCount=Debits-Credits*;

Notes:

- first line adds a column called NetCount of type integer
- second line updates it to be the difference between debits and credits
- sql commands are in caps, information specific to you is in italics

Good luck!